# '/bin/sh -c bash $METEORD_DIR/on_build.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: meteor, docker, docker-build

I'm pretty new to docker and what I want to do is to create a docker image of my Meteor App then run it in a container. (I'm working on OSX)

Correct me if I'm wrong but the steps are:

1)cd /myMeteorApp
2)create a file Dockerfile containing in my case `FROM meteorhacks/meteord:onbuild`
3) `docker build --tag jeromevi:mycoolmeteorapp .`
4) `docker images` and here I have that:
[image]

Someone can help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong please ?

[EDIT] The screenshot bellow is what happened when I created my image
[image]

Comment: Most probably the docker build was not successful.Are you sure it did not error out?

Comment: Look [EDIT] I'll add a screenshot but this error is not important for me because I don't want to run the apps I just want to create an image for the moment... or maybe I'm totally missunderstanding the message

Comment: the message `returned a non-zero code: 1` , means that the on_build.sh exited on a error.Their was some error , because of which the build was not complete and hence the tag was not set.

Comment: Ughh and do you know why this happend ?

Comment: I don't know much about Meteor.Found a similar issue ,look at this link : https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteord/issues/95 .Also add your dockerfile , i will try inspecting that.

Comment: My Dockerfile is "empty" he only contains `FROM meteorhacks/meteord:onbuild`

Comment: I have found a solution look the answer

Comment: Great! , best change the question description with the correct(meteor) issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone has the same problem as me I have resolved it with

https://github.com/jshimko/meteor-launchpad

Thank you to @Rambler for the help